# Echo table is not centerd?

Tags: html, css, formatting, alignment

I am working on a database search and I am trying to center everything. Input field and button are perfectly centered, the table that appears after an item is searched is moved a little bit to the right.

The form comes from the index.php, while the table comes from do-search.php which is displayed inside the first file. Why is this?

Type "Bayonet" in the search bar to see the problem:

> http://ni______________.nitrado.net (Sorry, have to censor again!)

```
Index.php: http://pastebin.com/bFXBfq2v  
do-search.php: http://pastebin.com/DQV28pTJ  
my.css: http://pastebin.com/LbXBTkYg
```

I am new to php/mysql/css and i mostly need this for a single project, so I apologize for the dirty code...

Greetings,
Thomas

P.s. I will use include db.php to log into the database as soon as everything works. :)

---

**Solution:** "Table is centered but button and input are moved a bit to right because of margin: 5px. Use margin: 5px 0; instead, it will add margin only to top and bottom."

Thanks to everyone. Case closed! :)

Comment: Since the `ul` should have `li` as direct children, I suggest you remove the `ul` and use the div like this instead `<div id="results" class="update">`.

Answer (score 0):

Table is centered but button and input are moved a bit to right because of `margin: 5px`. Use `margin: 5px 0;` instead, it will add margin only to top and bottom.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! <3

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the form, not in the table. You have a 5px margin in your input elements. Set margin-left to 0.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! <3

Answer (score 0):

Case closed: "Table is centered but button and input are moved a bit to right because of margin: 5px. Use margin: 5px 0; instead, it will add margin only to top and bottom."

Totally didn't see this!

Thanks to everyone!